# comboBox2 (or any particular form item) is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a win-forms. Currently working on the `.cs` class called `HM_Settings.cs` which works in conjunction with `HM_SettingsForm`.

I am trying to access the variables of the form items, by declaring these global variables

```
    public Brush backgroundColor;
    public Brush textColor;
    public double timeOffset;
    public double dateOffset;
    public string title;
    public bool showTitle;
    public bool showText;

    public HM_SettingsForm hmf = new HM_SettingsForm();
```

I am trying to use the form's variables by assigning them to the global variables, like so:

```
title = hmf.textBox1.Text;
showTitle = hmf.checkBox1.Checked;
showText = hmf.checkBox2.Checked;
```

The above should work. However, I am struck with this error, telling me it is inaccessible due to its protection level.

[image]

As a result, I tried changing certain values from `private` to `public`, but to no avail. What could I do?

Comment: What do you have changed from private to public?

Comment: Usually the designer generates private members of controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controls defined inside the `HM_SettingsForm` class using the WinForms Designer are private by default, so it is not possible to reach their property from an external class.

You could change the property Modifiers using the WinForms Designer  or directly modifying the `HM_SettingsForm.Designer.cs` file and set it to `public`, but I don't recommend to resolve the problem in this way.
Leaving open access to the internal controls of a form could lead to problems in future.
(A spectacular breach of the encapsulation rule of OOP)

Instead I suggest to create, inside the HM_SettingsForm class, some public properties (with only the get accessor) that returns the internal values of these controls.
(You have also the benefit to add your own custom code if the need arises)

For example, you could write this property inside the HM_SettingsForm class

```
public class HM_SettingsForm:Form
{
     // Of course, here a more meaningful name 
     // is a must for future readers of your code
     public string ComboBox2Text
     {
         get{return this.combobox2.Text;}
     }
}
```

As a side note, not actually related to the current question but....
It seems an error to return a string and assign that value to a Brush object.

Comment: Hi Steve. Do I put this inside the same `HM_Settings` class or in my `HM_SettingsForms` class?

Comment: Inside the form class where the controls are defined, then the instance of your HM_Settings can read the values

Comment: Thank you Steve. Worked perfectly. Out of curiosity, what is the desired return type for a OK and Cancel button? I am currently doing `public bool button1Click { get { return this.button1.Enabled; } }`. This is called in main by `public void ShowForm()
        {
            hmf.ShowDialog();

            if (hmf.button1Click) {`. Is that OK?

Comment: Search about examples for the [Form.DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: Currently using `hmf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK`. Is that the right implementation? I notice that is the standard for most forms programming. Could you explain to me a little what that does? I also have one in an `if-else` for `DialogResult.Cancel`.

Comment: A form opened with `ShowDialog` ends itself when any button on its surface has been clicked and its DialogResult is set to anything but `DialogResult.None`. The value of the button property is then passed in the `DialogResult` property of the form and you read the result as return value from `ShowDialog`. Also you could set the properties `AcceptButton` or `CancelButton` on the form. Then, if you click one of them, the form terminates itselft and returns `DialogResult.OK` or `DialogResult.Cancel`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is in my forms: http://puu.sh/6u7aj/9da2b71de1.png While this is in my main: http://puu.sh/6u7bA/f2d7e37e5b.png (Notice the `if` and `else` statements). I followed an old template my coworker did in VB, which I ported to C#. Is this the right implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Your controls are either `private` or `protected`. View the code behind file of your form and create properties to access the values. This will allow you to access the data without accessing or modifying the accessibility of the controls directly.

```
public string ComboBox2Text
{
    get
    {
        return comboBox2.Text;
    }
}
```

Then, in your first form, do

```
backgroundColor = hmf.ComboBox2Text;
```